Berge's theorem of maximum's application to expenditure minimisation problem
Let $f:X\times A  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function, and $\Gamma:A  \rightrightarrows X$ be a non-empty, compact-valued and continuous correspondence, with $X$,$A$ be Euclidean Space.
Define $v(\alpha)$ as $\sup_{x\in \Gamma(\alpha)}f(x,\alpha)$ and $X^*(\alpha) = \arg\max_{x\in \Gamma(\alpha)}f(x,\alpha)$. Then $X^*$ is non-empty, compact-valued and upper semicontinuous, and $v$ is continuous.
This is the standard formulation of theorem of maximum, but I'm struggling to apply it to the expenditure minimization problem.
By the fact that negative infimum of a function is supremum of negative, I think the results follow as the expenditure function $e(p,\bar u)$ is continuous, and hicksian demand correspondence $h(p,\bar u)$ is non-empty, compact-valued and upper hemicontinuous, if the correspondence $V(t):=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^N_+| u(x) \geq\bar u\}$ is non-empty,compact-valued and continuous. Is this correct?
Further, if it is correct, then under what condition(s) of utility function $u$ we can say the correspondence $V$ satisfies above conditions? I read some texts state follows: if $u$ is upper semicontinuous then $e$ is lower semicontinuous; if further u is locally nonsatiated then we have $V$ satisfies all conditions given above. But I have no idea how to prove it

$V(t)$ will usually be unbounded and, therefore, not compact.
